# How to change item to DONE in agenda view?

Tags: org-mode

I moved from Omnifocus to Org-mode. I liked the ability of Omnifocus to mark an item as DONE from the "due list", which corresponds to Agenda view in `org-mode`, by hitting `SPACE`. I tried `S-RIGHT`, which works to cycle the state of an item in the normal view, but in agenda view it changes a date. I could not find it in The Org Manual. I have to press `RET`, which brings the buffer, then change the state there. Does `org-mode` have a shortcut for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use key `t`. I just found it in the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html#Agenda-commands) under `Remote editing`:

```
t     (org-agenda-todo)

    Change the TODO state of the item, both in the agenda and in the original org file.
```